# autopopulate latitude and longitude coordinates into excel using python

Tags: python

I am working on a homework problem that gives only gives me store location information with city, and state. I'd like to write a python script or possibly an excel macro that gives me the ability to search this into google and grab the lat/long coordinates. I have over 2000 rows to do this with and thought there has to be a simpler way to do so. I ultimately want to bring this into my sample database and plot these coordinates on a map. I apologize in advance for this rudimentary question, so it seems.

Comment: I think the best idea is to find a database that includes city coordinates and use that to find your lat-long instead of searching into google every city in your database. Once you have that database, mapping is very easy with python (and excel I think). This link  may help you find the right databse: https://simplemaps.com/resources/free-country-cities

Answer (score 1):

For this project you will need to use the Google API and googlemaps library which you can install via:`pip install googlemaps`. It is not a difficult code, so let's begin:

1. First of all we will need to get our API Key, for doing that just follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=es-419) from google.
2. Once we have our API key, probably we won't be able to use it because you won't have any GoogleAPI enabled. To solve that just go to this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?), click on "ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES", search for `Geocoding API` which will be the one we will use and click on Enable.
3. Once we're done with that, probably we still won't be able to use it because we don't have any billing related to the project. Enter this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable) and associate a billing to the project. (First create a billing methof if you don't have one, don't worry, it's free).
4. Finally when all has been setted up we can start coding, the code you need should look like this:

   `import googlemaps
   api_key='YOURAPIKEY'
   gm=googlemaps.Client(key=api_key)
   geocode_result=gm.geocode('Country or location')[0]
   print(geocode_result['geometry']['location'])`
5. You can tune up this basic code to make a for loop for every location you need and to write the output data in an excel instead of printing it, but that's your work as you have to choose what to do with it.

Note: I've tried using 'Spain' as location and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRHxC.jpg) you can see the output.